# XML Parse Error - Extra Content at end of document

Tags: php, xml

I've been following a tutorial to create an XML Page using PHP. Below is the code.

```
<?
header('Content-type: text/xml');

mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "Select * from `books`";
$q   = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


$dom = new DOMDocument();

$datas = $dom->createElement('datas');
$dom->appendChild($datas);

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $id = $dom->createElement('id');
  $idText = $dom->createTextNode($r['id']);
  $id->appendChild($idText);

  $title = $dom->createElement('title');
  $titleText = $dom->createTextNode($r['title']);
  $title->appendChild($titleText);

  $author = $dom->createElement('author');
  $authorText = $dom->createTextNode($r['author']);
  $author->appendChild($authorText);

  $book = $dom->createElement('book');
  $book->appendChild($id);
  $book->appendChild($title);
  $book->appendChild($author);

  $datas->appendChild($book);

}


$xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xmlString;

?>
```

But for some reason when I run this I get an error which is - "error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document"

Comment: View the source of your page (or look in the "Network" tab of your browser's dev tools) to see *exactly* what PHP is outputting.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized the host I use adds antithetical code :/ I removed it and it worked :)